# Changing the Moodle template

Tags: themes, moodle

I want to use free moodle template from http://www.themza.com/. In its demo it shows how to install theme. It says put the theme on ftp. I put it in the same directory in local and it didn't work. I want to know it's because it's on local or I have another problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like they are not working because the themes are designed for Moodle 1.9 which is quite old now.

The latest version of Moodle is 2.6

http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Theme_changes_in_2.0